# How to use the isalpha function to remove special characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to remove special characters from each element in a string. The below code does count the elements but i can't get the .isalpha to remove the non alphabetical elements. Is anyone able to assist? Thank you in advance.

```
input = 'Hello, Goodbye hello hello! bye byebye hello?'
word_list = input.split()

for word in word_list:
    if word.isalpha()==False:
        word[:-1]
di = dict()
for word in word_list:
    di[word] = di.get(word,0)+1

di
```

Comment: you have to do it like this? or regex is allowed?

Comment: The single line `word[:-1]` does not do anything, and it's not clear what you *think* what it *should* be doing there either.

Comment: `' '.join([''.join([ch for ch in ss if ch.isalpha()]) for ss in in_str.split()])` and you should avoid using `input` as a named variable. It is a function in Python.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are expecting `word[:-1]` to remove the last character of word and have that change reflected in the list `word_list`. However, you have assigned the string in `word_list` to a new variable called word and therefore the change won't be reflected in the list itself.

A simple fix would be to create a new list and append values into that. Note that your original string is called `input` which shadows the builtin `input()` function which is not a good idea:

```
input_string = 'Hello, Goodbye hello hello! bye byebye hello?'
word_list = input_string.split()
new = []
for word in word_list:
    if word.isalpha() == False:
        new.append(word[:-1])
    else:
        new.append(word)

di = dict()
for word in new:
    di[word] = di.get(word,0)+1

print(di)
# {'byebye': 1, 'bye': 1, 'Hello': 1, 'Goodbye': 1, 'hello': 3}
```

You could also remove the second for loop and use `collections.Counter` instead:

```
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(new))
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution using re:

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: a = 'Hello, Goodbye hello hello! bye byebye hello?'
In [3]: ' '.join([i for i in re.split(r'[^A-Za-z]', a) if i])
Out[3]: 'Hello Goodbye hello hello bye byebye hello'
```

Comment: If using re, why not simply kick out all undesired characters instead?

Comment: are you talking about re.sub to substitute special characters with empty string?

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there with your `for` loop. The main stumbling block seems to be that `word[:-1]` on its own does *nothing*, you need to *store* that data somewhere. For example, by appending to a list.

You also need to specify what happens to strings which don't need modifying. I'm also not sure what purpose the dictionary serves.

So here's your `for` loop re-written:

```
mystring = 'Hello, Goodbye hello hello! bye byebye hello?'
word_list = mystring.split()

res = []
for word in word_list:
    if not word.isalpha():
        res.append(word[:-1])
    else:
        res.append(word)

mystring_out = ' '.join(res)  # 'Hello Goodbye hello hello bye byebye hello'
```

The idiomatic way to write the above is via feeding a list comprehension to `str.join`:

```
mystring_out = ' '.join([word[:-1] if not word.isalpha() else word \
                         for word in mystring.split()])
```

It goes without saying that this assumes `word.isalpha()` returns `False` due to an unwanted character at the end of a string, and that this is the *only* scenario you want to consider for special characters.

Comment: `if not word.isalpha():` tests the entire *word*, but `res.append(word[:-1])` always removes the last *character*. However, it works for OP's example and it's unclear whether this is by design or purely accidental.

Comment: @usr2564301, Yep, I was in the process of writing an extra sentence (see update). It's obviously an assumption based on current logic.